# Overriding user IP in Google Analytics measurement protocol is not considered by filters

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Adding the `uip` and `ua` parameters to the measurement protocol was really a great enhancement. Now, we can write server-side code that sends GA hits passing the client IP as the sender.

I ran a few tests, and it seems the filters that exclude some IPs are not really working on the passed IP value but rather the actual user IP.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

If you think this is a bug you should [file an issue](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/entry?template=Measurement%20Protocol%20-%20Defect) for it. Stack Overflow is generally not the best place to get questions like this answered.

The link I provided will be read by people who are actually working on the Google Analytics APIs, not just its users.

Comment: Thank you, Philip, for providing the link. Just posted it there under #482 for anyone who wants to follow up. https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=482

Comment: Got the answer that explained it. It's not a bug. User IP is automatically anonymized when the user IP is passed explicitly to override the server or proxy IP. Thanks

Comment: Hi @HazemMahsoub! Did you ever solve this issue? Alas, your ticket was closed by Google with no explanation.

Comment: Yes. This thread explained it to me:
https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=482
Basically, the IP anonymization will be turned on by default which will affect some filters but not all.
This is not the perfect behavior but at least I understood what's happening and could plan for.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get filters to work with the user's IP address? If the field is anonymized what good is it? Especially if you can't use if for filtering views?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to exclude ip adresses using the measurement protocol and GTM. It's a workaround and the downside is that it filters the sessions from ip adresses for all data-views. In the server container in GTM, simply add a new variable in which you receive the ip_override input from the event data. Then exclude that variable in your GA trigger. If you have a lot of ip adresses to exclude, then also make a lookup table variable in which the input is the ip adress and the output 'internal_ip' for example. Set your trigger to fire when the variable Lookup table is not internal_ip.